# jquery reordering of children based on value of title attribute

Tags: jquery

With jQuery, how can I reorder the list below by the title attribute from largest to smallest (i.e. rateplugin6 would be the first, rateplugin2 would be second, rateplugin8 would be third, rateplugin3 would be fourth, and so on)?

```
<div id="rateWrapper">
 <div id="rateplugin1" title="2"></div>
 <div id="rateplugin2" title="4"></div>
 <div id="rateplugin3" title="3"></div>
 <div id="rateplugin4" title="1"></div>
 <div id="rateplugin5" title="0"></div>
 <div id="rateplugin6" title="5"></div>
 <div id="rateplugin7" title="1"></div>
 <div id="rateplugin8" title="4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: There are a lot of [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+sort+div). None is helping? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

What about this [blog post](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/jquery-sorting-elements/)?
You will have to **modify the sort function** (called sortAplha) in the example.

**How to get value from that class?** You can use substring:

```
var class = $(this).attr('class');
var classValue = parseInt(class.substring(10)); // should remove 'rateplugin' and convert the rest to int
```

So the sorting function in your case ***might look like***:

```
function yourSort(a,b){
  var aClass = a.attr('class');
  var aValue = parseInt(aClass.substring(10));
  var bClass = b.attr('class');
  var bValue = parseInt(bClass.substring(10));

  return aValue < bValue ? 1 : -1;
}
```